# Best approach to bind datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview, bindingsource

At the moment I bind my datagridview in a following manner

```
relations = new CalculationsDataRelations();
bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = relations.Relations;
DgvRelations.DataSource = bs;
DgvRelations.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
DgvRelations.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

The potential problem I see here is what would happen if I change colums order or insert a column in `relations.Relations` object.

Is it possible to avoid situations like this and set properties of columns not by index ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access columns by names. This will still be a subject to bugs if you change column names, but probablity is much lower.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the right columns index using the column name of the datasource

[Method to Find GridView Column Index by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925183/method-to-find-gridview-column-index-by-name)