# Hide GridView Column using Gridview's DataField

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I have a gridview and I wanna hide some columns using gridview's datafield. I mean 
I use normally GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false; and it works. But for big gridviews it's complicated. Is there  a way to do it using DataField for a asp.net gridview. There is a way for telerik radgrid below.

```
RadGrid.MasterTableView.GetColumn("ID").Visible = false; ("ID" --> datafield of grid)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edited for updated question**

**In ASP.NET GridView:**

```
private int GetColumnIndexByName(GridView grid, string name)
{
    foreach (DataControlField col in grid.Columns)
    {
        if (col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            return grid.Columns.IndexOf(col);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Then use that helper function to set your visibility:

```
int column = GetColumnIndexByName(GridView1, "ID")
if ( column != -1 )
{
    GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3925334/1674958

**In Telerik RadGrid**

Server-side:

```
protected void gvCktMap_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    gvCktMap.MasterTableView.GetColumn("sid").Visible = false;  
    gvCktMap.MasterTableView.GetColumn("customername").Visible = false; 
    gvCktMap.MasterTableView.GetColumn("marketname").Visible = false; 
    gvCktMap.Rebind(); 
}
```

Source: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/how-to-hide-columns-in-radgrid.aspx

Client-side:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
function Button1_Click() 
{ 
    var radGrid = $find('<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>'); 
    var table = radGrid.get_masterTableView(); 
    var column = table.getColumnByUniqueName("cbDiscontinued"); 
    table.hideColumn(column.get_element().cellIndex); 
}
```

Source: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/chart/how-can-i-hide-unhide-columns-in-rad-grid.aspx

Comment: Thanks for helping. Actually I looked at that link but I am looking for a direct using like in radgrid.

Comment: The original question was a little misleading.  Updated answer to include the Telerik RadGrid.

Comment: Actually the original question was what I asked. But someone changed it. I updated it again. Your first answer was okay but I need a direct using. I mean in telerik we can use something like that --> radgrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumn("ID").Visible = false;--  But I guess we don't have something similar for asp.net