Hiding a Gridview row based on the result of a stored procedure in SQL Server VB.NET
I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that checks the permission of the user who wants to see my gridview.
The procedure returns 1 if they have permission and 0 if they do not.
I want to show the column 'Salary' only to those who have this special permission.
this is my aspx page:
 'Hide Salary Column 
 Dim IsPermitted As Integer
 Using cmd As New SqlCommand("stored_procedure_IsPermitted")
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDnumber", "4257673")
     cmd.Connection = con
     con.Open()
     IsPermitted = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
     con.Close()
 End Using
 If IsPermitted = 0 Then
     GridView.Columns("Salary").Visible = False -> this line gets the error
 Else
     GridView. Columns("Salary").Visible = True
 End If

This is my code and I don't understand why I get this error:

Conversion from string "Salary" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Can you please help.
Thanks a lot in advance.

As an aside https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

edited the code and i am showing which row runs on error

i am not sure, i dont have idea how to fix it, can you please recommend something?

I'm guessing you need GridView.Columns[5] where 5 is whatever 0-based index the salary column is, or maybe GridView.Columns(5), i haven't used vb in years

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfieldcollection.item?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-web-ui-webcontrols-datacontrolfieldcollection-item(system-int32) seems you can only index it by number... not sure why your compiler doesn't throw an exception though, you couldn't even write that code in C#.

@DaleK, it's almost certainly because the project settings include Option Strict Off, which is the default. That allows implicit narrowing conversions and late binding, making VB.NET work much like VB6. Everyone should set Option Strict On in the VS options, so it will be On by default in future projects, as well as setting it On in current projects. That will make VB.NET work much like C#. Off means beginners don't have to think about data types as much, which makes mistakes like this easier to make.

'GridView.Columns()' expects an int32 as a parameter. Not a string like you're giving it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925183/method-to-find-gridview-column-index-by-name has the answer you need to retrieve your column properly. I encourage making this an extension method to simplify this if you need to retrieve a column by Header or datafield later.

The columns for a asp.net (webforms) GridView can't be indexed or referenced by a name, but you have to use an integer value (index) for the GridView. So, you’re passing a name, and vb.net is attempting to convert that string into a number.
So, if you used "2", or better yet 2, then that would be a valid integer "index" into the column.
So, you can look at the GridView, and count the columns, (starting at 0), and enter the column number. Say, like this:
GridView.Columns(3).Visible = False

Or, you can use the posted code in the other answer here. However, keep in mind that any templated columns for a GridView don't require a heading name.
Hence, it is best to simply use the index, since those columns may well not have a heading text anyway.
It would help if you posted the markup of the GridView you are currently using.
For the time being, I suggest using an integer index for the column, and not a name.
However, you can adopt a column search by name routine (such as suggested in the other post) that will return a column based on heading text passed. This will allow use of a column name in place of an integer index number for referencing the columns in the GridView.
So, in your global helper code module, you can use this function:
Public Function GetColumnByName(MyColumns As DataControlFieldCollection,
                                sColumnName As String) As DataControlField

    Dim sResult As DataControlField = Nothing

    For Each dColumn As DataControlField In MyColumns
        If dColumn.HeaderText = sColumnName Then
            sResult = dColumn
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return sResult

End Function

And then your code becomes this:
    If IsPermitted = 0 Then
        GetColumnByName(GridView1.Columns, "Salary").Visible = False
    Else
        GetColumnByName(GridView1.Columns, "Salary").Visible = True
    End If

Which could be shortened to:
GetColumnByName(GridView1.Columns, "Salary").Visible = (IsPermitted = 1)


Assuming you are using the GridView, you must provide the 0 based index of the column you wish to access when accessing as Gridview.Columns(int32).
To achieve what you are aiming for, I recommend the following:
public module DataControlFieldCollectionExtensions
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Retrieves the first DataControlField from the GridView.Columns collection with the matching Header Text.
    ''' <exception cref="ArgumentNullException" />
    ''' <exception cref="InvalidOperationException" />
    ''' <param name="dcfc">The DataControlFieldCollection to search.</param>
    ''' <param name="ht">The headerText to search for.</param>
    ''' <returns>The first DataControlField with the headerText equal to ht or nothing if it does not exist.</returns>
    '''</summary>
<Extension()>
    Function FindByHeaderText(dcfc as DataControlFieldCollection, ht as string) as DataControlField
        if string.isNullOrEmpty(ht) then throw new NullArgumentException("Header text cannot be empty string")

        if dcfc.count = 0 then throw new InvalidOperationException("Column collection may not be empty.")

        For i as Integer = 0 to dcfc.Count-1
            if dcfc(i).HeaderText = ht then return dcfc(i)
        Next
    End Function

    return nothing
end module

    'Hide Salary Column 
    Dim IsPermitted As Integer
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("stored_procedure_IsPermitted",con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        
        'don't use add with value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDnumber",sqldbtype.nvarchar).value = "4257673"

        Try
            con.Open()
            IsPermitted = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        Catch
            ' handle exceptions if desired or default IsPermitted to 0 to make sure that 
        Finally
            if con.state <> connectionState.closed then con.Close()
        End Try

    End Using

    Try
        dim salaryColumn = GridView.Columns.FindByHeaderText("Salary")
        if salaryColumn isnot nothing then salaryColumn.Visible = (IsPermitted = 1)
    Catch ex as exception
        'Do Something if exception thrown?
    End try

